# Measures of Borel Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to reason through the following problem. (**Note**: $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$)

> For a subset $E\subset[0,1]$, put $U_{\varepsilon}(E)=\{x~:~|x-y|<\varepsilon~\mathrm{for~some}~y\in E\}$. Is it true that for every Borel set $E\subset [0,1]$, $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}m(U_{\varepsilon}(E))=m(E)$? Does this limit hold for every closed subset of $[0,1]$?

I'm really not sure how to determine if the statement is true or false (and, moreover, how to prove my answer). I was thinking that as $\varepsilon\to 0$, we may have some sort of decreasing sequence of sets and thus be able to use the continuity of measure. Is this the direction I should take this, or am I completely off track? Thanks in advance for any help -- it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: For the first question, consider $E=[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Simon Is that supposed to be a counter example?

Comment: Yes. This $E$ has measure zero, but $U_\epsilon(E)=[0,1]$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Comment: That makes so much sense. I don't know why I didn't see that!

Comment: It works for *closed* sets $E$.

Comment: @GEdgar I think I can see why it holds for closed sets. Is that where I could use the continuity of measures?